# How can I install a WordPress theme without a FTP server?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I have a WordPress site in my localhost and I want to install a theme, but it is telling me that I need a FTP server to do that. How can I install it without a FTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your localhost, you have to go to your WordPress main folder. Then, when your on WordPress' root directory, got to `/wp-content/themes`.

Copy/paste your unzip theme folder in this `/wp-content/themes` folder.

Go back to your WordPress BackOffice, and you should see the new theme next to the others.